# How to modify/append inside a function in Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object, append

In one of my js files, I am using a jquery-UI dialog function to display both confirmation messages and user inputs, according to parameters of the function.

( The following question is more about “the way to do it” if it is possible, rather than about “jquery-UI dialog”, that's why I titled this topic with “Javascript” )

Here is the simplified content of my function, to focus on the question :

```
function dialog_Handler({title, message, buttons, input}){

    // Creates object with autoOpen: false to be able to modify it before opening
    var dialog = $("<p>" + message + "</p>").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        open: function(event, ui){
            $("div.ui-widget-overlay").css({"background": "#000", "opacity": "0.4"});
            $(".ui-widget-overlay").hide().fadeIn();
        },
        title: title,
        buttons: buttons,
        modal: true,
    });

    // Adds some more configuration if input needed
    if(input){
        // Adds input field right under the message
        dialog.dialog({
            open: function(event, ui){
                $("div.ui-widget-overlay").css({"background": "#000", "opacity": "0.4"}); // SAME AS ABOVE
                $(".ui-widget-overlay").hide().fadeIn(); // SAME AS ABOVE
                $(this).append('<br /><br /><input type="text" value="' + input + '"><br />');
            },
        });
    }

    // Dialog opening
    dialog.dialog("open");

return;}
```

As you can notice, when input is needed (!= false), I have to “append” an instruction in the “open” function of dialog.

Is there any way to add something in the function instead of rewriting it completely ?
Something that would look like this ?

```
        dialog.dialog({
            open: function.append{
                $(this).append('<br /><br /><input type="text" value="' + input + '"><br />');
            },
        });
```

Thanks in advance for any reply.

Comment: Use the conditional statement within the `open` callback

Comment: My conditional statement `if(input)` does other things than only the one I shared with you. That's why I doesn't use it in the `open` callback. I could duplicate it, but I look for a way not to duplicate neither the instructions nor the conditional. But I agree that would be a little nicer, yep!